# Any alternative to Dukt Analytics?

Tags: dashboard, dashboard-widgets, analytics

I am unable to pay $99 for [Dukt Analytics](https://dukt.net/analytics). Does anyone know of a free alternative that gives me google analytics stats for the dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/?q=analytics& shows some possible analytics candidates.

Particularly these:

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/instant-analytics

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/piwik-analytics

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/3redkites-piwik-analytics-for-craft-cms

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/tracker